# How to have a non query based scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can I turn a filter on an array of ActiveRecord objects into a *scope*?

For example turn this:

```
Users.all.collect { |u| u.has_super_powers? }
```

Into:

```
scope :supers, #something here
```

The point is that it can be used as a scope so Users.all is not always "**all**" like:

```
Users.undeleted.supers.find_by_this('that')
```

I thought maybe using lambda expressions in scopes is the way, but don't think that would work since I don't have access to records as the expression is added to a DB query and not run as a post step over the results.

Comment: What is `has_super_powers?` Scopes will only work on data inside the database, not Ruby methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends wether or not you can transform `u.has_super_powers?` into a database query. Sometimes it is possible, sometimes its not.

For example: If you have a database field `has_super_powers (boolean column)` in the users table you can create a scope on that:

```
scope :has_super_powers, where(:has_super_powers => true)
```

Now you can chain it together with other scopes:

```
User.undeleted.has_super_powers.find_by_this('that')
```